# Oracle create pdb manager user

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I create user C##ADMIN in database for manage pdbs .

```
sqlplsqlplus sys/rootpass@172.17.0.2/orcl as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat May 26 15:17:09 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create user C##ADMIN identified by adminpass container=all ;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION, SYSOPER,PDB_DBA,DBA, CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TO c##admin CONTAINER=ALL ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

My problem is C##ADMIN user can not list pdbs !

```
sqlplus C##admin/adminpass@172.17.0.2/orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat May 26 15:20:14 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sat May 26 2018 15:17:32 +04:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select pdb_name,status from cdb_pdbs;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Which permission is forgotten?

Comment: What is cdb_pdbs if you query all_objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How the Oracle Multitenant Option Affects Privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html#GUID-576B2B6F-A368-438A-842B-BFFAEFAA535D)

> A common user connected to the root can see metadata pertaining to
>   PDBs by way of the container data objects (for example, **multitenant
>   container database (CDB) views** and V$ views) in the root, **provided
>   that the common user has been granted privileges required to access
>   these views and his CONTAINER_DATA attribute has been set to allow
>   seeing data about various PDBs.**

```
SQL> create user C##ADMIN identified by adminpass container=all ;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION, SYSOPER,PDB_DBA,DBA, CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TO c##admin CONTAINER=ALL ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn C##ADMIN/adminpass
Connected.
SQL> select PDB_NAME from cdb_pdbs;

no rows selected
```

Granting the required privilege:

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter user c##admin set container_data=all for cdb_pdbs container=current;

User altered.

SQL> conn C##ADMIN/adminpass
Connected.
SQL> select PDB_NAME from cdb_pdbs;

PDB_NAME
---------
PDB$SEED
PDB1
```